# show color dropdown on frontend magento

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. I want to show color dropdown on the frontend product detaails page. I have added the attribute 'color' and attribute set 't-shirt' from backend and also created a product and assigned the attribute set. yet am unable to show on the frontend. I am using magento 1.7 version. I want that the user can select the color from dropdown from the frontend.
Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a configurable product to add a dropdown for color.

Comment: I have already tried creating a configurable product and simple product. I am using blanco theme from themeforest.

Comment: Refer to this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/

Comment: The previous link seems to be outdated. Following is an updated link for anyone who visits here..... :) https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html?Highlight=configurable%20product